# How do I create the onClick function for a button with Kotlinx.html?

Tags: html, kotlin, ktor, kotlinx, kotlinx-html

I am using Kotlin's html library kotlinx.html for dynamic html building.

I want to create a button which triggers a function when clicked. This is my current code:

```
class TempStackOverflow(): Template<FlowContent> {
    var counter: Int = 1

    override fun FlowContent.apply() {
        div {
            button(type = ButtonType.button) {
                onClick = "${clicked()}"
            }
        }
    }

    fun clicked() {
        counter++
    }
}
```

This results in the following source code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="kotlin.Unit">testkotlin.Unit</button>
```

Which gives this error when clicked (from Chrome developer console):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: kotlin is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

I have tried several approves, and search for a solution - but could not find the proper documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're completely missing the point of the kotlinx.html library. It can only render HTML for you, it's not supposed to be dynamic kotlin->js bridge, like Vaadin or GWT. So, you just set result of `clicked` function converted to String to `onClick` button's property, which is effective `kotlin.Unit`, because `kotlin.Unit` is default return value of a function if you not specify another type directly.

```
    fun clicked() {
        counter++
    }
```

is the same as

```
    fun clicked():Unit {
        counter++
    }
```

and same as

```
    fun clicked():Kotlin.Unit {
        counter++
    }
```

So, when you set "${clicked()}" to some property it actually exec function (your counter is incremented here) and return Koltin.Unit value, which is becomes "Kotlin.Unit" string when it rendered inside "${}" template

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
I am desperately searching for a platform for my app, so I kind of rushed into using it. Thanks for enlightening me.

I will try to move towards Kotlin + JS/React. I am currently working with React at other projects and I should provide what I need.

Comment: Excellent choice, Kotlin for backend, JS/React for frontend is a wise decision

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Kotlin expert, but it's perfectly possible to write event handlers using kotlinx. Rather than:

```
onClick = "${clicked()}"
```

have you tried using this?

```
onClickFunction = { clicked() }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a bit on Javascript here, you can type this:

```
   unsafe {
      +"<button onClick = console.log('!')>Test</button>"
   }
```

Good for debugging and tests, but not very nice for production code.